# ipad 2 compass?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, core-location

I need to know if iPad 2 has a built-in compass and still responds to:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
```

the exact way the iPhone does. Any differences I should know about?

Can anyone help me? I only got my hands on an iPad for a very short while and I get no callbacks for this method. The app works well on iPhone 3GS/4

Thanks!

=============

My code looks like this:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)meter didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {

switch (currentOrientation) {
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        self.viewAngle = atan2(acceleration.x, acceleration.z);
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        self.viewAngle = atan2(-acceleration.x, acceleration.z);
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
        self.viewAngle = atan2(acceleration.y, acceleration.z);
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        self.viewAngle = atan2(-acceleration.y, acceleration.z);
        break;  
    default:
        break;
}

[self updateCurrentCoordinate];
```

}

But I get My heading from the GPSReader

Comment: Note that the original iPad also has a compass.

Answer (score 0):

iPad2 comes with 2 versions:-
WiFi Only and WiFi + 3G
http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/

Location
Wifi Only
* Wi-Fi
* Digital compass

Wifi+3G
* Wi-Fi
* Digital compass
* Assisted GPS
* Cellular

if you could tell what exactly you get as iPads don't have the same method. I've the same issue and when i went deep down, it complexed me more.

Can you give scripting of x, y and z axis with filtering Factors and adjustments?
do you care to share your kFilteringFactor? don't exactly know what to use for that one, but may be that can also be helpful.

Comment: It is an iPad with 3G and I am not using any kFilteringFactor. Look above for the didAccelerate method